# Add a user to a Google Group from GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have play around with the Group Class implemented in the default services of Google Apps Scripts. However, there is no way to add a new User to a group, when one is manager of that group. On the other hand, Google Apps Provisioning API allows to do just that. Is there a way to connect that API from GAS? Any insights on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To add a user to a group you can use the [Domain Group](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_domaingroup) service. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
var group = GroupsManager.getGroup("testgroup").addMember("nick@example.com");
```

**Update 18 Aug 2016:**
Google [announced the deprecation of the DomainService (which includes GroupsManager) on 15 May 2015](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/deprecating-scriptdb-and-domain-service.html). You can use the [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) now instead.

This sample adds a user to an existing group in the domain. It is copied directly from the documentation.

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'liz@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'bookclub@example.com';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```